# Where should I ask a broad programming question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would like to ask this question, but I am not sure to what community it belongs:

> I've been a frontend developer for some years, but sometimes I'm still
>   in doubt as to which HTML tag to use in a certain situation. Do you
>   know of any books or websites that gives authoritative explanations of
>   the most important tags and their usage? (I am looking for some more
>   synthetic resource than the w3 specification itself, as I find it most
>   of the times long-winded)

This doesn't seem to fit stackoverflow, because it's not a specific programming problem. I would like to gather resources on the matter: **is there any community where this question would fit**?

Answer (score 6):

Nowhere on Stack Exchange.

Both Stack Overflow and Programmers have a "too broad" and "request for external resources" close reasons, either of which would apply here.

This isn't to say that you've got a bad question - just one that doesn't fit the Stack Exchange question and answer model.